# rmarkdown template in R package fails when I add create_dir: true

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm following the RStudio [Guide to Document Templates](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_document_templates.html) to include a template within an R package.  The example works through "Template Basics."  But I get an error when I get to "Supporting Files" and I add `create_dir: true` to my `template.yaml` file, or when I add another file to the `skeleton` directory, both of which cause RStudio to prompt the user to specify a new directory in which to create the new file.

When I re-install the package and try to create a new RMarkdown file with my template, I get the error popup:

> Couldn't create a template from C:/ ...*[package directory]*... at C:/ ...*[desired output directory]*...  Error occurred while executing method

And in the RStudio console the error message is:

```
Error in (function (file, template, package = NULL, create_dir = "default",  : 
  template.yaml must contain name and description fields
```

But the RStudio guide says nothing about a description field and I can't find an answer via Google on RMarkdown + YAML + "description."  What's causing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer when examining the `template.yaml` files in the [markdowntemplates package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/markdowntemplates) on GitHub.  They specify a `description` in the YAML header, like this:

```
name: Kube Template
description: >
  Kube template
create_dir: true
```

For the case of the RStudio tutorial linked above, adding this second line to my `template.yaml` got the example working:

```
name: My Template
description: My Template
```